# How do I know if the ODE has a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

Given IVP, for $x \in  (-5, 5) $ and $ t \in R $

$$ \frac{dx}{dt}  = \sqrt{|x|}$$

$$ x(0) = 0 $$

I want to find if it has a unique solution or not.

So I use the Picard theorem:

1. Either I check if $\sqrt(|x|) $ is continuous or not and $\partial f/ \partial x$ is continuous or not in our given range (-5,5).  If both conditions holds, then I can say that a unique solution exists. And it could be found using Picard iterates.

Here, in 1, we would check for continuity of $\partial f / \partial x$ right? where $f (x, t) = \sqrt(|x|) $ . I mean the variables could be anything like $x,y,t,z,w...$ all we need to check is for the variable given there. (It's because if it's not in $y$, I get confused in visualizing, so maybe I can just put in $y$ in place of $t$ and visualize?)

2. It may happen that 1. may fail or it is very difficult to compute the partial derivative, in which case we check for the condition for $f(x, t)$ being lipschitz continuous in the given range.

$$ |f(t,x1) - f(t,x2)| \leq  L |x1 - x2| $$

So here , I need to find an L such that this holds:
$$ \frac {|\sqrt|x1| - \sqrt|x2||} {|x1 - x2|}  \leq L $$

If the function is differentiable everywhere on the given range, then I can use the Mean Value Theorem.

and for $f(x1) - f(x2) \leq  f'(c) (x1 - x2) $ for some $ c$ between $x1$ and $x2$ and for $x1 < x2$ for all $x1, x2 \in (-5,5)$
And then I can take absolute values on both sides and say that we can take any $L$ such that $|f'(c)| \leq L$ we found a bound.

a. How do I find the value of L? I can put $x1, x2$ as the boundary values of the interval, and how do I choose $c$?

b. I can apply MVT only if the function is differentiable, what if the function is not differentiable in the given range?

Also, Picard's theorem is only a sufficient condition, what do I do if the conditions for Picard Theorem fails? Is there any example where Picard's theorem fails and the IVP still has a unique solution? I think such a function would not satisfy the Lipschitz condition. But I need an example.

This is my understanding, Please suggest how do I approach such problems. I don't require a trick or direct observation of this particular problem. I want to learn general construction so I can verify the existence and uniqueness of solution for any IVP.

Comment: @fundamentalform isn't x(t), the solution of the IVP we are trying to find, with a given initial condition of x(t0) = x0 ?

Comment: So first off, in your problem the Picard theorem does not apply, because $f(t,x)$ is not Lipschitz in a neighborhood of zero. This does not immediately imply non-uniqueness. To actually see the onset of non-uniqueness, *explicitly find* two solutions with $x(0)=0$. One can be found by separation of variables; can you find the other one? (I am sorry to say that there is not actually a nice necessary-and-sufficient kind of theory for this topic.)

Comment: @Ian Yes I understand that Picard theorem is not a necessary, but only a sufficient condition. So there might be a unique solution, or more than one solution. And in that case an approach would be to try finding a solution explicitly using one of the established methods (as you suggested Variable separable helps here). But I am more concerned about my approach in verifying conditions for Picard's theorem and other things in regard to my approach and mistakes in it. Please help me, how did you arrive at $f(t,x)$ is not Lipschitz in a nbd of 0?

Comment: $\frac{|f(t,x)-f(t,0)|}{|x|}=|x|^{-1/2}$ blows up as $x \to 0$. Note that on the other hand, assume WLOG $x>y>0$ then $\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}{x-y}=\frac{x-y}{(x-y)(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$. As a result $f$ is Lipschitz on any domain bounded away from zero, and so the only possibility for non-uniqueness is if it either starts at zero or the dynamics transport it to zero.

Comment: (Cont.) That last detail is one reason why a clean necessary-and-sufficient uniqueness theory is basically impossible to construct. For instance, I cannot look at this problem and see anything local going on at a negative value of $x$ that suggests that there should be non-uniqueness in the IVPs for negative values of $x_0$. But there is anyway, because the dynamics in these cases transport the system to $x=0$ where there is some locally weird behavior.

Comment: In principle there is nothing special about zero, but I think that question suggests some misunderstanding of the specific things happening in this problem. To help illuminate that, consider that $x'=\sqrt{|x|}+1$ has unique solutions to its IVPs, even though the RHS is not Lipschitz at zero again. (You can see this because in this case the RHS never vanishes and so you can always separate variables.)

Comment: @Ian I see, that makes sense. So a function may not be lipschitz in the given range, but could still have a unique solution in that range. For this particular problem, the lipschitz condition fails but it still gives solutions. And since in this case  for range [0,5]  it wont be lipschitz since in the nbd of 0, it fails to be lipschitz, But simple moving ahead of 0, we see that we found a unique solution. Also here we can tell the function blows up in nbd of 0, what if, it was some function for which we cannot find such a bound L directly and if it is lipschitz around the given initial point?

Comment: Without at least having "locally Lipschitz on each compact set", there is not really anything general you can do without examining dynamics, because the dynamics might transport you to wherever local Lipschitz happens to break down from anywhere. (For an example of that criterion without global Lipschitz, consider $y'=y^2$, to which Picard-Lindelof can in fact be applied. This has finite time blowup, but that's another matter.)

Comment: @Ian So you mean that I need to assess how the graph/extrema/critical points/ differentiability of the function or in general where the  function might behave in  a different way by looking at the function? Also thank you for the very detailed response. Do you recommend anything else from the question details above? If so, then please suggest? 
Also, for $y' = y^2$ and $y(0) = 0$, we check $y^2$ is continuous in neighborhood of any (x,y) and $\partial f/\partial y = 2y$ is continuous so that's why we can use Picard-lindelof.

Comment: @Ian So this means that for Picard Lindeloff to hold, we need only locally lipschitz and not globally lipschitz RESTRICTED ON THE COMPACT SET. (it may not be globally lipschitz, but here we dont even need globally lipschitz on the compact set restriction on which it is locally lipschitz)?

Comment: Also, if I try to verify lipschitz condition for this (Apart from checking Picard's conditions using partial derivate's continuity and the function's continuity on the range) $\frac {|y1^2 - y2^2|} {|y1 - y2|} \leq C$ Here, how do I find out if such a bound C will exist, and if it exists then how do I find its value?

Comment: Oh I just found out, locally lipschitz on compact set will imply globally lipschitz restricted to that compact set. So in general we just need to check locally lipschitz on the compact set and this goes both ways, since lipschitz => locally lipschitz always, while locally lipschitz => lipschitz as long as we are on a compact set.

Comment: Sorry if I introduced some technical confusion, the word "locally" in "locally Lipschitz on compact sets" is indeed redundant. I could just as easily have said "Lipschitz on bounded sets".

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much for the clarification and also for your time. I understand it  much better now from your explanation. 

Also,  So for the bound C above I have,  I can't use MVT since $y^2$ is not differentiable at 0. So far I have $ \frac {|y1^2 - y2^2|}{|y1 -y2|} = |y1 + y2| $  If I take y1 < y2 (WLOG)  so we have the whole thing $ \leq |2y2|$ which is our bound C  I think.

Comment: @Ian  And for y2 to be infinity, this will fail and hence local lipschitz, but not global lipschitz (from your explanation above)

Comment: You can use MVT, because $y^2$ is differentiable everywhere. From that you get that $2R$ is a Lipschitz constant for $y'=y^2$ confined to $[-R,R]$. This diverges as $R \to \infty$, so $y^2$ is only locally Lipschitz and not globally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular problem, if you didn't immediately kind of see what was going on to be able to take a shortcut, you would start with this computation. For $x \neq y$:

$$\frac{|\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|y|}|}{|x-y|}=\frac{||x|-|y||}{|x-y|(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|})} \\
\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}}.$$

You recognize that this is exact when $x,y$ have the same sign or just one of them is zero (so you haven't done some kind of blunt estimate that completely changes the behavior).

Therefore, how can you make $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}$ very small? Make $y=0$ and then consider $x \to 0$. You do that and you conclude that your $f(t,x)$ is not Lipschitz in $x$ near zero.

This means that Picard-Lindelof can't be applied if the trajectory would pass through zero at some point. This may or may not imply non-uniqueness.

In this case, it gives a hint that there might be non-uniqueness for solutions that hit zero. And indeed you can find two solutions with say $x(0)=0$ by hand. One of them is identically zero, another is $\operatorname{sign}(t) t^2/2$ which can be seen by separation of variables. More generally there are actually infinitely many solutions to this problem, determined by the interval on which you choose to have $x=0$.

But this phenomenon is not determined solely by the regularity, it is also determined by the detailed behavior of the dynamics. In particular, this behavior does not occur for $x'=\sqrt{|x|}+1$ (which has exactly the same situation with respect to the hypotheses of Picard-Lindelof). In this case separation of variables works without any division by zero anywhere. The problem is that this "singularity" in $x'=\sqrt{|x|}$ requires the dynamics to become very slow as $x$ approaches zero (but not so slow that zero cannot be reached in finite time at all). This doesn't happen with $x'=\sqrt{|x|}+1$.

Generally, there is not really a nice necessary-and-sufficient condition for existence/uniqueness in ODEs. The local version of Picard-Lindelof works in most situations we frequently encounter, but when it is not applicable, we tend to need to do things on an ad hoc basis.